# How do I preview data in a JSON file that resides in GCS?

Tags: cdap, google-cloud-data-fusion

I'm playing with **Google Data Fusion** for the first time (it got released into beta about 4 hours ago) and the first thing I'm trying to do is something fairly dumbed down - read the contents of a JSON file that resides in a GCS bucket.
The GCS source seems like an obvious thing to do. I've configured it like so:

[image]

If I click over to the Preview tab I see a message

> Preview Data for the stage "Google Cloud Storage" is not available.

Is this because of something I have done wrong or because the GCS source doesn't support previewing data? I'll be slightly disappointed if its the latter, previewing data would be very very useful in a tool like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make all fair points and we will address them and improve the experience. Totally understand what you are saying.

Nitin

Answer (score 1):

OK I figured out the problem, the service account that the Data Fusion instance is running as needs access to the storage buckets. When I granted that access (by adding the service account to legacy storage admin & Storage Object Viewer roles) the error message went away (it was replaced with another error message, but that's one for another thread).

There are a number of problems here tho:

- I only figured out the problem when I tried to run the pipeline and saw a useful error message in the logs ("`<service account> does not have storage.buckets.get access to <bucket>`"). There was no error message in the Preview tab to indicate what the problem was, the same error message should be showing up there.
- Wy can I not pick which service account I want the instance to use rather than it create one on my behalf?